# $\sum|B_n|$ converges then $\sum \left(3|B_n|+2\cdot B_n+\frac{\sin(n)\cdot B_n}{n}\right)$ converges

Tags: calculus

I'm studying to my finals and I was asked to prove the following, a bit strange, theorem:

> Let $B_n$ be so $\sum |B_n|$ converges. Then $$\sum\left(3|B_n|+2\cdot B_n+\frac{\sin(n)\cdot B_n}{n}\right)$$ is converges.

I don't understand how to prove it. I don't how anything about $B_n$. I only know about $|B_n|$. How should I prove it?

Comment: Actually, saying that $\sum|B_n|$ converges is the same as saying the series $\sum B_n$ is *absolutely convergent*, so you do know something about $B_n$.

Comment: Shouldn't that sum on $i$ be a sum on $n$? And isn't $\sin n\cdot B_n/n$ undefined when $n=0$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Actually It said in the exam $\sum |B_n|$ and so I though it was talking about $n=0$.

Comment: I would assume you were meant to think of it as $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $$\left|3|B_n|+2\cdot B_n+\frac{\sin(n)\cdot B_n}{n}\right|\leqslant 
3|B_n|+2|B_n|+\frac{|\sin(n)|}{n}\,|B_n|$$
$$\leqslant3|B_n|+2|B_n|+|B_n|=6|B_n|$$
(I used that $|\sin x|\leqslant |x|$ for all $x$, so $\frac{|sin n|}{n}<1$ for all $n$) and $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |B_n|$ converges, series: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(3|B_n|+2\cdot B_n+\frac{\sin(n)\cdot B_n}{n}\right)$$
is absolutely convergent and therefore convergent.

Comment: $|\sin x|\le1$ is good enough for this question.

Comment: That's true, since $\frac{|\sin n|}{n}\leqslant \frac{1}{n}\leqslant 1$.